# What are these colonies on my Bacillus pumilus lawn?

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques

I am growing *Bacillus pumilus* and I have plated some on agar plates. Now I can see some colonies on top of the lawn.

[image: lawn of *Bacillus pumilus* with unidentified colonies on top]

Does anybody know what they could be? A contaminant? *Bacillus pumilus*? I have observed some people growing *Bacillus pumilus*, and the colonies they streaked looked different than mine. Could it be that *B. pumilus* has several colony phenotypes?